# How to troubleshoot ECS Fargate container? | "502 bad internet gateway"

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have deployed a web app on the ECS Fargate cluster using Cloudformation. Basically, I have created a CICD pipeline with CodePipeline, CodeBuild, and BitBucket as a source code. I have deployed the whole infrastructure using cloudformation. I am following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/swlh/aws-cloudformation-managed-complete-ecs-infrastructure-including-ci-cd-pipeline-from-github-to-ecs-b833bb44e01c)
Everything went smoothly and successfully deployed but when I try to access the url of my app it throws an error, "502 bad internet gateway."

How I can troubleshoot this? When using EC2, we can go to that machine and we somehow got to know what's the issue. But in the case of Fargate there is no machine created. Kindly tell me how to troubleshoot this? What's the best approach should I follow to get the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Start by looking at the ECS console to see if the Faragte task is even running, or if it is failing to start for some reason. Then check the load balancer's target group to see if health checks are passing. If you need to connect into the running Fargate container to troubleshoot further, use [ECS Exec](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-exec.html).

Comment: My service is is running state but my healthy checks are failing, can you tell me why health checks are failing or the common reason for health check fails?

Comment: Either you've misconfigured the health checks (verify the path and port are correct), or your application is not returning a 200 OK response at the health check path for some reason.